# How to deal with very big values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

Using `Sybase ASE 15.7`, I've been asked to assess the feasibility of a complex calculation. Actually, the calculation is not complex at all, but it requires to deal with very huge numbers and to keep a very high decimal precision at the same time.

Here are my constraints:

- Everything must be performed within a stored procedure. No data can be imported into the database or exported outside the database (using other tools or programming languages would be a joke).
- I have to keep a precision of no less than 18 digits on the right of the decimal point (using the `DECIMAL` numeric type, I'm allowed to use a maximum of 38 digits, which means that I can only have 20 of them on the left of the decimal point).

Here is what my prototype looks like now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
(
    @X DECIMAL(38,18),
    @ALPHA DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_1 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_2 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_3 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_4 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_5 DECIMAL(38,18)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @POLY_1 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_1 = @ALPHA

    DECLARE @POLY_2 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_2 = @BETA_1 * @X

    DECLARE @POLY_3 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_3 = @BETA_2 * POWER(@X,2.0)

    DECLARE @POLY_4 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_4 = @BETA_3 * POWER(@X,3.0)

    DECLARE @POLY_5 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_5 = @BETA_4 * POWER(@X,4.0)

    DECLARE @POLY_6 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_6 = @BETA_5 * POWER(@X,5.0)

    DECLARE @POLY_SUM DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_SUM = @POLY_1 + @POLY_2 + @POLY_3 + @POLY_4 + @POLY_5 + @POLY_6

    SELECT @POLY_SUM

END       
GO
```

And here is an example using real data:

```
 EXEC dbo.MyProc 360, 0.000000000000000000, 3.001691154643420000, -0.004000558548191020, 0.000003108186568058, 0.000000000639528525, -0.000000000000517669
```

The result of the above example query is `NULL`. After tweaking my procedure a little bit:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
(
    @X DECIMAL(38,18),
    @ALPHA DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_1 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_2 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_3 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_4 DECIMAL(38,18),
    @BETA_5 DECIMAL(38,18)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @POLY_1 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_1 = @ALPHA

    DECLARE @POLY_2 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_2 = @BETA_1 * @X

    DECLARE @POLY_3 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_3 = @BETA_2 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,18),POWER(@X,2.0))

    DECLARE @POLY_4 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_4 = @BETA_3 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,18),POWER(@X,3.0))

    DECLARE @POLY_5 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_5 = @BETA_4 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,18),POWER(@X,4.0))

    DECLARE @POLY_6 DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_6 = @BETA_5 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,18),POWER(@X,5.0))

    DECLARE @POLY_SUM DECIMAL(38,18)
    SET @POLY_SUM = @POLY_1 + @POLY_2 + @POLY_3 + @POLY_4 + @POLY_5 + @POLY_6

    SELECT @POLY_SUM

END       
GO
```

I finally managed to obtain the right result: `714.763457289478656`.

Now, the real problem is that the first argument of the stored procedure, the variable `X`, ranges from a minimum of `1` to a maximum of `10000000`. As soon as the `X` values increases too much towards his maximum, I start getting arithmetic overflow problems 'cause, well... `500000^4` (just a random value within my range) grows up to `31250000000000000000000000000` and no numerical type can store such a big value.

I've read almost every blog article / SO post / tutorial concerning how to deal with very big numbers is SQL, but I found nothing that can help me out. Actually... is there a solution to this problem? And, if yes, which one?

I'm thinking about every possible approach... dividing my `X` by `10^n` and multiplying all the betas by the same value (this will only delay the moment of the failure), using a logarithmic base (not possible since betas can be negative), factorizing the function in order to reduce the exponents... I don't know...

Comment: Most SQL databases are not designed for such high-precision numbers (Postgres is an exception).  I would suggest that you implement a CLR procedure in a language more suited for this purpose.

Comment: Aaaah if only I could! It's a problem of policies. I can't extract/insert data in that DB... all I can do is process it in place.

Comment: Not perfectly sure it will help, but I found this link on decimal bigger than 38 : http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/X315932.htm

Comment: Off-topic, but with Mimer SQL you could have used `decimal(45,18)`.

Comment: Dosen't a CLR procedure execute inside the database itself? You won't be exporting data outside of it, just using a "dll written in another language" inside SQL

Comment: I don't think I have the user permissions to do that...

Comment: Part of me is wondering the purpose of calculations that can generate values between 724 and 3x10^28, with the idea being that perhaps a better understanding of the bigger picture might allow for some ideas ... ?  One idea would be to reduce values by 10^x, then use string manipulation to move the final decimal point (eg, 10000000 = 1x10^7 => perform calcs for input of 1; convert final value to a string and manually move decimal point to the right by 7 spaces) ... obviously limited if you lose decimal place accuracy ... also an issue if you can't use a string result

Comment: **punt** ... tell the client it can't be done with just ASE 15.7; then give client some (realistic) options; @Fleury26's link to the IQ manuals brings up an idea ... setup a remote/CIS connection between ASE and IQ, pass numbers to IQ proc, let IQ proc (using larger numerics) peform the calcs, then return a string (??) ... yeah, passes the data out of ASE but if client has an IQ instance then perhaps 'keeping the data in ASE/IQ' might be acceptable?